# OpenShift command line terminal does not oppen a connection in the OpenShift Developer Sandbox

Tags: openshift

After deploying a Node application from a github repository in the OpenShift Developer Sandbox, I can not open the OpenShift command line terminal

[image: Topology]

[image: OpenShift Command Line Terminal]

I can not find the **Open CodeReady Workspaces** either. Not sure if there is any relation though :

[image]

Did anyone face a similar issue ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

could you please try refreshing the page? if this does not work please add the events from the *-dev namespace to the description.

> I can not find the CodeReady Workspaces either.

CodeReady workspaces are now re-branded as Red Hat OpenShift Dev Spaces [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b09ba.png).
You can navigate to the Dev Spaces dashboard by clicking the "Aplications" button or simply navigating to https://workspaces.openshift.com/

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b09ba.png)https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/04/01/codeready-workspaces-scales-now-red-hat-openshift-dev-spaces